# Rails Magic Method model_ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to look up how to get just the IDs of Comments, an associated model to Post.

Post has_many Comments

I found through the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects) that you can use the .map method to pluck out just the IDs.

But then, for the heck of it, I tried doing:

```
p = Post.find(1)
p.comment_ids #[1,2,3]
```

And it worked!  I cannot find this magic-method documented anywhere in the Rails docs.  Is this an officially supported way to get has_many relation ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the doco of [`has-many-association`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference), you will find the detailed documentation.

`collection_singular_ids`:

> ... these methods, collection is replaced with the symbol passed as the first argument to has_many, and `collection_singular` is replaced with the **singularized** version of that symbol.

As per the [`singularize`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/singularize) method -

```
comments.singularize # => comment
```

In your case `collection_singular` has been replaced with `comment`. That's how you got `comment_ids` method.

Hope it clears to you.

Answer (score 2):

See the [has_many Association Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference):

> When you declare a has_many association, the declaring class automatically gains 16 methods related to the association:

Among them are:

```
collection_singular_ids
collection_singular_ids=ids
```